# Why the "Close Images" problem is QIP-complete

Tags: resource-request, complexity-theory, information-theory

The following problem is known as the "close images" problem:
the input is two circuits $Q_0$, $!_1$, with the same number of input
and output qubits (The circuits are allowed to add ancilla or trace-out qubits).

YES instances: There exists states $ρ_0, ρ_1$ such that $F(Q_0(ρ_0), Q_1(ρ_1)) ≥ \frac{3}{4}$.

NO instances: For any $ρ_0, ρ_1$ it holds that $F(Q_0(ρ_0), Q_1(ρ_1)) ≤ \frac{1}{4}$.

I have read in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0407056.pdf) article that this problem was proved to be QIP-complete. However, I couldn't find the proof itself no where (neither in the reference given in the above mentioned article)

Any help to formally prove this claim, or even just intuitively explain it, will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the article mentioned in your question:

> In fact, the problem [...] was only implicitly proved to be complete for QIP in Ref. [7], but all of the pieces needed to establish this fact are present in that paper.

Here they refer to "Parallelization, amplification, and exponential time simulation of quantum interactive proof system" by Kitaev and Watrous<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1145/335305.335387)</sup>

There is a whole chapter dedicated to the Close Images Problem in "Computational Distinguishability of Quantum Channels" by Rosgen<sup>[[2]](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.0909.3930)</sup> (chapter 4), you will find the proof for its QIP completeness there.